# contact lookup list only for related account

Tags: salesforce-id, account, contact, lookup

I have a contact lookup so when i click on the lookup it opens a popup and i search for a particular contact. what i want is to restrict the result to display only contacts related to a account, for example in my case object i have account field i also have contact field
when i click on the lookup of contact it should only show the contacts of the account. Do any body have any idea to do this. Please help me.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7494/restrict-contact-lookup-to-show-only-contacts-related-to-account-in-case-object/7495#7495                                                 You may like to refer this link

Comment: thanks that was nice but works only when we insert record through the object directly. Can you guide me how to do it through code. because i am trying to insert record from a VF page

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this using the Filtered Lookup feature.

[Defining Lookup Filters](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_lookup_filters_defining.htm)

Comment: thanks that was nice but works only when we insert record through the object directly. Can you guide me how to do it through code. because i am trying to insert record from a VF page.

Answer (score 1):

http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/

If you are using visualforce page for this one workaround is to roll your own salesforce lookup popup window .

The above blog has tips and tricks on how to achieve this

Comment: is the filters only work on a standard page, if we are using the field as apex:inputfield wouldnt the filter work like in standard page

Comment: Filters i personally have tried but with no luck.You can try though .Sometimes i used to get field "filter Validation Exception".let me also know if you are able to work for visualforce with filters